# What levels are needed to unlock Path of the Jedi in Angry Birds Star Wars?

Tags: angry-birds-star-wars

The extra levels in Angry Birds Star Wars titled **Path of the Jedi** can be unlocked by either buying a $2 IAP or 3-starring every level. Being a gamer at heart, I feel the latter one is the only way to go.

However, the fact that new levels are periodically added in free updates makes the concept of "every level" a bit vague. Does this also mean the bonus levels? How about the ones that aren't unlocked yet?

I believe the game was released before the Hoth levels; will they also be needed? I currently have Tatooine and Death Star 3-starred so at least completing Hoth or the Bonus levels is needed but do I need both?

Furthermore, should I avoid future updates if I want to unlock the levels faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can now answer my own question: the bonus levels aren't needed. The Path of the Jedi levels become playable when you 3-star all *currently available* standard levels - currently Tatooine, Death Star and the 20 Hoth levels that have been released so far.

I think it's safe to assume that new levels from updates need to be completed as well, so if you've almost completed 3-starring the levels it could be a good idea to refrain from updating the game before you finish unlocking Path of the Jedi.